# How to identify form action URI from processAction() method in Portlet class?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I created a form like;

```
<portlet:actionURL var="myFriendlyURI">  
<portlet:param name="action" value="addUser"></portlet:param>  
</portlet:actionURL>  

<form id="userForm" name="userForm" action="${myFriendlyURI}" method="post">  

 Name :- <input type="text" name="userName">  

 <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

In processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) method, how can I identify the request URI based on myFriendlyURI?

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri").toString()) is giving only "/web/portal/Adduser-PageName".
```

I just want to check the request just like we are doing in Servlet class ;

```
if(request.getRequestURI().endsWith("user/add")) { // <form action="user/add" ..... >
    System.out.println("Ends with :  user/add ");
    // do actions here
 }
```

Comment: Do you need the action URL, for any reason other than handling and managing different actions? I'm asking because if the action parameter is the only thing you need, you can do it without the URL processing

Comment: Why do you want the request URI? Do you want to filter multiple actions in your processAction?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
HttpServletRequest convertReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
HttpServletRequest originalReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(actionRequest);
```

[`PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL();`](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8865925)

Reference to the link has many examples

Comment: I'm trying to get it in processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response). There its expecting  HttpServletRequest instead of ActionRequest : PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(HttpServletRequest request).
Casting from ActionRequest to HttpServletRequest will give a class cast exception.

Comment: Edited my answer. Plz follow the link for more info.